# How to use a prop to form an image url

Tags: reactjs

I want to use the prop as part of the file name as part of the src for an image but I'm clearly doing something wrong.

I am passing on the name as string, and then using the name to form the url for the image. I've tried using the back tick "`" but that doesn't work either.

```
import React from 'react';

type AppProps = {
    name: string
    description: string
  }

const PartnerIcon: React.FC<AppProps> = ({name, description}) => {
  return (
    <div className="partner-icon">
      <img src="../images/{name}.svg" className="span-row-2"></img>
      <b>{name}</b>
      <p>{description}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PartnerIcon;
```

Comment: have you tried ` ../images/${name}.svg} ` ?

Comment: The path to the image is now correct but the image doesn't load?

Comment: You need to put images in public folder or import it in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string interpolation.

```
<img src={`../images/${name}.svg`} className="span-row-2"></img>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<img src={`../images/${name}.svg`} className="span-row-2"></img>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string interpolation like that :

```
<img src={`../images/${name}.svg`} className="span-row-2"></img>
```